# Is it possible to have Web-to-Lead and Web-to-Case forms in the same form?

Tags: web2lead, web2case

Just wondering whether it's possible to have the Web-to-Lead form and Web-to-Case form in the same form based on condition?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SFSE!. Please see [ask] on getting the most from the community. This could best be answered on stackoverflow as you are essentially putting two forms on the same web page. There are also resources on Google to help. SFDC doesn't care as long as the button submits the data to the right endpoint

Comment: Try generating the forms and then merging them. It is HTML after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won't say it's *impossible*, but the method that comes to mind is a very hacky workaround.

The method in question is:

1. Create a custom field (picklist value, or checkbox, or just designate a value for an existing text field) on the case or the lead object, whichever one you're going to use the web-to-X code for. Let's say Leads.
2. Create a flow that triggers on X (= Lead) creation, if the field is filled in . Have it create the other thing, and maybe also delete the created lead if you're feeling risky. Make sure to copy over whatever fields you need to the case you're creating from the lead that got generated. Case description = lead description, contact = whoever that contact was, et cetera.
3. When adding your web-to-X code, include a line to let your maybe-a-lead, maybe-a-case situation decide which one they are, which then fills in the field from step 1 appropriately.

For an example of step 3, this would be the picklist option method:

```
(Picklist Label Goes Here):<select  id="(ID of your field)" name="(ID of your field again)" title="(Picklist Label)">
<option value="">--None--</option>
<option value="(Ordinary Lead Option #1)">I'm interested in your stuff</option>
<option value="(Ordinary Lead Option #2)">I'm interested in your services</option>
<option value="(The One That Tells You This Is Actually A Case)">I have a problem</option>
</select><br>
```